# jquery error with socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I have just made a chat-room using socket.io and jquery. I was unsure about how to get it online so I just uploaded the files to an old ftp I had. (I am really new with node.js) Loading up the website was normal, but when I looked in the console there was an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):55)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ (index):55
j @ jquery-latest.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-latest.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-latest.min.js:2
J @ jquery-latest.min.js:2
```

The error is pointing to the `<script>` tag in the html code (the first variable set is where the error is):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var socket = io.connect();
        var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
        var $message = $('#message');
        var $chat = $('#chat');
        var $messageArea = $('#messageArea');
        var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
        var $userForm = $('#userForm');
        var $users = $('#users');
        var $username = $('#username');

        $messageForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
            $message.val('');
        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data){
            $chat.append('<div class="well"><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>: '+data.msg+'</div>');
        });

        $userForm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('new user', $username.val(), function(data){
                if(data){
                    $userFormArea.hide();
                    $messageArea.show();
                }
            });
            $username.val('');
        });

        socket.on('get users', function(data){
            var html = '';
            for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
                html += '<li class="list-group-item">'+data[i]+'</li>';
            }
            $users.html(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am wanting to put this website online and run it with the socket.io and node.js as it's part of a larger project I am working on. If I am doing it completely wrong, I am sorry. Can you guys help me fix this error or tell me what I'm doing wrong please. 
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import socket.io library before your script definition:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```